# Different URL to point to django admin view

Tags: python, django, url, admin

In my app, 'admin/appname/modelname/add' goes to an admin view to add/change the object.
I want 'admin/appname/modelname/add' to point to a different view (this much is already done), and then a new url (say admin/makenewmodel) to point to the same view that admin/appname/modelname/add points to.
I can't just redirect it to /add because that now points to my newer view. How can I direct my own url straight to the admin view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override get_urls() of your ModelAdmin. Check out my answer
[Django Admin - Custom changelist view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814157/django-admin-custom-changelist-view/6814957#6814957)  (the question is almost identical to yours)

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py, url are tested in the order ex:

```
url ('admin/appname/modelname/add', 'your view 1')
url ('admin/appname/modelname/add', 'your view 2')
```

It will ask the view 1 and not the view 2. Can you use that to overwrite URL by adding a 'url' at the top ?

Comment: that's how I've done the first redirect, but I still need to redirect my new url to the django admin add view.

Comment: url ('admin/appname/modelname/add', 'my view 1')
url ('admin/makenewmodel', {django admin view})

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf